# how to write a list in a file with a specific format?

Tags: python, list

I have a Python list and wanna reprint that in a special way.

input:

```
 trend_end= ['skill1',10,0,13,'skill2',6,1,0,'skill3',5,8,9,'skill4',9,0,1]
```

I want to write a file like this:

output:

```
  1  2  3 
1 10 0 13
2 6  1  0
3 5  8  9
4 9  0  1
```

Basically, I need to do the following steps:

1. Separate elements of the list for each skill.
2. Write them in a table shape, add indices of columns and rows.

I wanna use it as an input of another software. That's why I wanna write a file.

I did this but I know it is wrong, can you see how I can fix it?

```
f1 = open("data.txt", "a")
for j in trend_end:
    f1.write(str(j))
for i in range(1,int(len(trend_end)/df1ana.shape[0])):
    G=[trend_end[i*(df1ana.shape[0]-10)- (df1ana.shape[0]-10):i*(df1ana.shape[0]-10)]]
    for h in G:
        f1.write(i)
        f1.write(h)
    f1.write('\n')
f.close()
```

`df1ana.shape[0]`  is 3 in the above example. It is basically the length of data for each skill

Comment: You should iterate over the list in steps of 4.

Comment: @Barmar I can not get the format of the output that I was presented in the above

Comment: can your columns/index start at 0 instead of 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option that you can try via `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([trend_end[i+1:i+4] for i in range(0,len(trend_end),4)]).to_csv('data.txt', sep='\t')
```

`OUTPUT`:

```
    0   1   2
0   10  0   13
1   6   1   0
2   5   8   9
3   9   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the list in steps of 4, i.e. `df1ana.shape[0]+1`

```
steps = df1ana.shape[0]+1
with open("data.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write('   ' + '  '.join(range(1, steps)) + '\n') # write header line
    for i in range(1, len(trend_end), steps):
        f.write(f"{i:<3}")
        for j in range(i, i+steps-1):
            f.write("f{trend_end[j]:<3}")
        f.write("\n")
```

The `:<3` formatting puts each value in a 3-character, left-aligned field.

Comment: `I:<3` do you mean `steps` by 3??

Comment: No, that's the width of the field in the output. So it puts each number in a field 3 characters wide.

Answer (score 0):

This should work regardless of the number of groups or the number of records per group.  It uses the difference in the size of the full list compared to the integer only list to calculate the number of rows you should have, and uses the ratio of the number of integers over the number of rows to get the number of columns.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

digits = [x for x in trend if isinstance(x,int)]
pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(digits,
                        (int(len(trend)-len(digits)),
                         int(len(digits)/(len(trend)-len(digits)))))).to_csv('output.csv')
```